# Linq to SQL SubmitChanges() not working if textbox modified by listbox

Tags: linq-to-sql, submitchanges

In a simple test form, I have a listbox and a textbox.  The form is bound to a datacontext, which has a single table. The listbox has two items, and is not bound.  The textbox is bound to the datacontext.

When I select an item from the listbox, the following code runs:

```
txtTest.Text = lstTest.SelectedItems(0).ToString
```

Then when I push my Save button, the following code runs:

```
Me.TextDC.SubmitChanges()
```

But - the database field which the textbox is bound to is NOT updated.

If I manually type in a value into the textbox and then push the Save button, the database field IS updated.

I've been trying to solve this on and off for several days, and I finally made this very simple text form to confirm or deny what was happening.  No errors occur.

So, for some reason SubmitChanges() does not recognize that the textbox needs to be updated if it's .Text property has been updated from the listbox, but does recognize that it needs to be updated if I manually type in a value.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  Somehow, I don't know how exactly, the connection string to SQL Server in the dbml file and the connection string in the application settings file were slightly different.  I made absolutely sure they were both pointing to the same sql server database, and all works correctly now.